# Showing a sequence is contractive

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x_1>0$ and $x_{n+1}=3+2/x_n$

I got $|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}|=|3+2/x_{n+1}-3-2/x_n|=|2/x_{n+1}-2/x_n|=2|(x_n-x_{n+1})/(x_{n+1}x_n)|$

I'm not sure what to do now since $x_1>0$. Can I just take an abitrary $x_{n+1}>0$ and $x_n>0$ and replace them at the last step? How can I show that $x_n$ is contractive?

Comment: What is your goal?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify it. Just edited. It is to show that $x_n$ is a contractive sequence

Comment: You can show that $x_n>3$ if $n>1$

Comment: Is it enough to say that for $n>1$, $x_n>3$ because $x_{n+1}=3+2/x_n>3$?

Comment: Yes, and $x_n >0$ for all $n$. To be precise, you need to show that by induction.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = 3+ \frac{2}{x}$, then $f'(x) = -\frac{2}{x^2}$. Note that $|f'(x)| \le \frac{1}{2}$ whenever $x \ge 2$.

Notice that $f(x) \ge 3$ for all $ x \ge 0$. Since $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$, it follows that $x_n \in X=[3,\infty)$ for all $n > 1$. From above, we have that $f$ is a contraction on $X$, hence $|x_{n+1}-x_{n}| = |f(x_{n})-f(x_{n-1})| \le \frac{1}{2} |x_n - x_{n-1} |$ for all $n>2$.

Since $X$ is a complete metric space and $f$ is a contraction on $X$, it follows that the sequence converges to a unique fixed point in $X$.

The fixed point can be computed by solving $f(x) = x$ with $x \in X$. This gives the equation $3x+2 = x^2$ to get $x = \frac{1}{2}(3+\sqrt{17})$.

Comment: But you don't really need to appeal yo the mean value theorem here: $f(x)>3$ for $x>0$, so $x_n,x_n+1>3$ if $n>1$ and $2/(x_nx_{n+1})<2/9$.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: Very nice. Two buck chuck made me use a sledgehammer approach!